# Installing Apache tomcat using bash script using Java

Tags: java, shell, automation

Hi I'm planning to devolep a APP that will install install programs using bash commands Ie to install tomcat

apt-get install tomcat7

Is it possible to achieve it programmatically using Java

Comment: as you added `automation` tags as well so I personally use `ansible` if you want to use you can try it out http://docs.ansible.com/

Comment: Please be elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Runtime.exec()` method to run external command. For more refer: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_exec.htm